# Get iCal link for Facebook Page's events

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events, icalendar

I'm trying to get the iCal link for a Facebook Page's events. I can get one that is for my events, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get an iCal feed that covers all the page's events (regardless of whether I'm personally attending them). I'm an admin on the page.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to get this via Facebook natively. Even playing with the AJAX calls which pull up the iCal event will result in an error if switching via personal profile to page.

[image: Use Facebook as]