# How do I view a Facebook Page events' in Calendar Format?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events, icalendar

Either how do I export just one Facebook Page's events' into ical format so I can view in my preferred format or how can I view it in Calendar format. I know you used to be able to do that for your own going events but that seems to have changed to a scheduled view which is also acceptable.

I've also asked on Facebook Help Community [How do I view a Facebook Page events' in Calendar Format?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2006556592706693)

I know this is a partial duplicate of [Get iCal link for Facebook Page's events](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79039/get-ical-link-for-facebook-pages-events) but that is 3 years old and doesn't ask for calendar view.